# Laravel use url() or route() to serve https URLs if the page loaded via https

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Is there a way so all `route()` and `url()` can be overridden to force serve https URLs if the page loaded via https?

We're currently using cloudflare and it already converts http to https but for some reason, when you visit e.g. *https://www.website.com/some-page*, the generated URLs via `route()` and `URL()` aren't automatically converted from http to https. is there a way so I can force the schema to https?

Comment: Check if you are meant to use something like `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` when using cloudflare SSL offloading. Your server doesn't think it is over HTTPS so laravel thinks it's http.

Comment: As @jedifans your server probably does not send `X-Forwarded-Proto: https`. This often happens when using cloudflare **Flexible SSL**. Try creating self-signed certificate on your server and switch to **Full SSL**.

Answer (score 3):

I used below code and it's working for me:

```
   if (!\App::environment('local')) {
              \URL::forceSchema('https');
         }
```

Add this code in Path: \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php boot function

replace APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=production on root .env file.

Comment: i have actually tried this but it only works locally. upon deploying on our cloudflare hosted server, it doesn't take effect for some reason

Comment: it's working fine on live cloud server.
did you make above both changes?
because we also faced same issue few days ago and fix that by above code.

Comment: if possible can u please share both file code so that I will check and let you know if you are making any mistake

Comment: @bonbon.langes that's probably because cloudflare is accepting HTTPS requests, but converting them to HTTP and sending to your server. Neat thing done by cloudflare but gets confusing sometimes.

Comment: Note: method renamed to forceScheme (not -a) in newer versions.